# Finding $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{x^{100}}{x^3-y^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

What is $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{x^{100}}{x^3-y^2}$?

Comment: The limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Yup limit does not exist. I just wanted to highlight that sometimes unusual paths are to be found out in order to prove that the multivariate  limit does not exist...

Comment: What did you highlight? And what are the unusual paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Take the path for approaching the origin to be parametrically described by $x=t$ and $y=t^3+t^n$.  What is the limit for $n=1$?  What is the limit for $n=101$?

Comment: Is it possible to show with conversion to polar coordinates that the limit does not exist?